# ICMP Requests working but HTTP requests are timing out

Tags: data-connection

For some context, please see this image: http://db.tt/JPJlBC5b (I will upload to SE when I am in front of desktop)

Basically this issue happened once before. What's happening is my phone basically stops connecting to the internet. HTTP requests seem to just simply time out after a few minutes in the browser. This causes all my apps to break and some of these apps fail more gracefully than others.

The weird part is I can still PING and TRACERT DNS names and IP addresses via ICMP. so I still have some sort of internet connection. If I toggle airplane mode or reboot my phone it fixes it, but only for a few minutes before it stops working again.

Last time it seemed to fix itself. Or something. I got so annoyed at trying to fix it that I just went to sleep. When I woke up, everything was broken, even my cellular connection. A quick reboot and everything, including my data connection, was working.

Is there anyway I can try can figure out what's causing this and make it stop?

Comment: Are you sure it is not some carrier imposed limit?

Comment: Yes. I have unlimited data.